# Oracle create procedure query throwing error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have one create procedure query i m trying to execute it in Oracle Database.Below is the query :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROC IS
TYPE TESTTABLE IS TABLE OF a.TEST102%ROWTYPE;
```

Synatax of the query seems to be fine but when i am executing it is throwing below sql exception.

**Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
   . ( @ % ; not null range alter character**

Trying to find out the issue trying all possible ways from past two days but i did not get any idea wheres the issue is.Can anyone please suggest what is wrong with the query???? Would be great if some one can help me out here.

Comment: Is that the entire code for the procedure?  Where's the `begin .. end; /`?

Comment: yes it is the entire code for the procedure is it wrong????

Comment: If we have to use begin and end in the above query how do we add it...sorry i am new to oracle so asking ...

Comment: The procedure won't do anything without a begin/end enclosing some actual work. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i an just trying to create one procedure of specific datatype so is the above query...can u tell me one example of the create procedure query with some specific type.

Answer (score 0):

the following will work:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST102(id number);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROC IS
TYPE TESTTABLE IS TABLE OF TEST102%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    NULL; -- insert procedure body here
END;
```

Comment: This will still get a PLS-00103 because there's no begin/end.

Comment: @user587092: make sure that table TEST102 is existant and valid

Answer (score 0):

Procedures must have BEGIN..END block.
Here is a procedure that does not do anything.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROC 
IS
  TYPE TESTTABLE IS TABLE OF dual%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
```

Comment: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
              
                 ( ; not null range alter index character
              ,

Comment: Edited to use dual%rowtype. Works on Oracle 9.2

Comment: Works in 11.2 as well. The original gets PLS-00201 'identifier must be declared', not PLS-00103, so I think we must be missing something about how the OP is executing the command?